# Rails 4.0 User Authentication/Signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently doing this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-ribbit-in-rails/

but tried to update it to 4.0 myself since it seems a bit outdated.

https://github.com/erosenberg/myribbit

One of the things that stands out to me is that the tutorial was using 'attr_accessible' whereas I was using a private method to define the params for users to signup.

The solution doesn't have to match the tutorial (I only just got to the part with Sessions) but I would love to be able to see how to fix this specific error that isn't making sense to me and constantly sending me down a rabbit hole:

ArgumentError in Users#new. wrong number of arguments (1 for 0).
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `current_user'

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of my error in case nobody else is seeing it: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code: https://github.com/erosenberg/myribbit/blob/master/app/controllers/application_controller.rb#L7

`session [:user_id]` should be `session[:user_id]`.

Comment: First of all, wow! Thanks for the fast response. I'll keep looking but I could've sworn I double checked spellings 20-30 times! It's the little things...

Comment: Yes, the master branch should be the latest version that's giving me the error. And, based on the tutorial mentioned above, it did instruct me to do "Users" instead of User.

Comment: The error should be present when simply running the server and going to localhost:3000.

It causes the whole app to break.

Comment: Yes but with a different error than what you've posted: http://pastie.org/8212400 and it actually makes sense. I've updated my initial answer.

Comment: Wow thank you SO much. I can't even believe it was something so stupid on my part. I should've seen that from a mile away! I wish the errors were easier to understand instead of making me think I was sending the incorrect number of arguments through the form. You are seriously a savior. Thanks!

Comment: @eightonrose You're welcome. Programmers suck at paying attention to detail :P